# Need Infragistics three state XamCheckEditor to cycle null->*true*->false instead of null->*false*->true

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, infragistics

I have a `XamCheckEditor` in three state mode (IsThreeState == true).

The default value is null which displays the indeterminate grey box (which is good).  But then when a user clicks the checkbox the value assiged is unticked (cleared).  The user has to click twice to get it to be ticked (checked).  Would like instead to have the first click change the value to ticked (checked).  How can this be achieved?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not specifically familiar with Infragistics controls, but assuming they operate as most all other WPF controls do you should be able to override the `Click()` event and therein manage the control state precisely based on the control's value / state at click time.

Something along the lines of (pseudo-code):

```
private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (checkBox1.InfragisticsValue == null)
        checkBox1.InfragisticsValue == true;
    else if (checkBox1.InfragisticsValue == true)
        checkBox1.InfragisticsValue == false;
    else if (checkBox1.InfragisticsValue == false)
        checkBox1.InfragisticsValue == true;
}
```

I hope that helps ^^.

post-comment-edit

After your comment I did a bit of searching for hopeful guidance.  If you're working with a 'load-on-demand' check-box control (has multiple states), try visiting [this link](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/jordan_tsankov/archive/2012/01/21/infragistics-jquery-tree-load-on-demand-checkboxes-and-keyboard-navigation.aspx); I suspect it may prove useful.

Comment: Hmm, not anything obvious in Infragistics like this.  There are things like PropertyChangedEvents and AutomationPeers.  Tracing through the debugger is not revealing anything like a simple click handler.  Still digging.  Thanks very much for the response.

Answer (score 0):

This should be submitted as a feature request to Infragistics.  You can do this by posting on the forums or submitting a support case.  Links to both are available from the [get help page](http://www.infragistics.com/support/get-help.aspx).